# magento2 bin/magento indexer:reindex this command delete the data from catalog_product_index_price

Tags: magento-2.1, importexport, indexing, indexer

I am uploading products via xls and this is working fine.I am uploading bundle/simple products

After that when all process complete. then I run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` by script for reindexing.

This deletes the bundle item data from mysql table `catalog_product_index_price`, and if I running `bin/magento indexer:reindex` using command prompt then this is working fine.

Comment: Share the script that you are running

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that your script is not loading the correct area either cli or frontend and as such an event/plugin is not being loaded correctly.

What you could also consider is rather than calling the indexer via `bin/magento` you could inject the price indexer, something like `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price` into your code and call execute on that.